# Is there a smart way to inhibit hiding a operator function of base class by one of derived class

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning c++ for a while.
 I would like to make a pointer class with curiously recursive template pattern, like following. Unfortunately, it did not work because default operator==() function of derived class hides operator==() function of base class. Do we have a smart way to inhibit hiding operator function of base class by one of derived class? Or do you know a way to avoid this issue? 
In case, I append messages from compiler.
Thank you very much.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename Derived, typename T>
class Function0 {
public:
    friend bool operator== (Derived& org, Derived& cmp) {  // ***** This line gives a warning
        Derived& org_value = static_cast<Derived&>(org);
        Derived& cmp_value = static_cast<Derived&>(cmp);
        return *(org_value.value_) == *(cmp_value.value_);  // *** old code: return org_value == cmp_value;
    }
};

template <typename T, template <typename Derived, typename T_T> class Functions>
class Pointer : public Functions<Pointer<T,Functions>, T> {
public:
    Pointer() {};
    Pointer(T* new_value) : value_(new_value) {};
    bool operator== (Pointer& cmp) = delete;  // ***** This line gives a warning
    virtual ~Pointer() {
};
private:
    friend Functions<Pointer<T,Functions>, T>;
    T* value_ = nullptr;
};

class TestA {
public:
    TestA(unsigned int id) : id_(id) {};
    virtual ~TestA() {};
    unsigned int id(void) { return id_; }

    bool operator== (TestA& cmp) {
        return (id_ == cmp.id()) ? true : false;
    }

private:
    unsigned int id_ = 0;
};

template <typename Element>
Element findCorrespondingFirst(Element& obj, std::vector<Element>& vec) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        auto o = vec[i];
        if (obj == o) {  // this dispatches an error massage
            return o;
        }
    }
    return Element();
}

void test_pointer_class(void) {

    std::vector<Pointer<TestA, Function0>> ptr_vector;

    TestA* raw_ptr0 = new TestA(1);
    TestA* raw_ptr1 = nullptr;
    TestA* raw_ptr2 = new TestA(2);

    Pointer<TestA, Function0> ptr0 = Pointer<TestA, Function0>(raw_ptr0);
    Pointer<TestA, Function0> ptr1 = Pointer<TestA, Function0>(raw_ptr1);
    Pointer<TestA, Function0> ptr2 = Pointer<TestA, Function0>(raw_ptr2);

    TestA* raw_ptr3 = new TestA(1);
    Pointer<TestA, Function0> ptr3 = Pointer<TestA, Function0>(raw_ptr3);

    ptr_vector.push_back(ptr0);
    ptr_vector.push_back(ptr1);
    ptr_vector.push_back(ptr2);
    ptr_vector.push_back(ptr3);

    auto result1 = findCorrespondingFirst(ptr3, ptr_vector);

    delete raw_ptr0;
    delete raw_ptr1;
    delete raw_ptr2;
    delete raw_ptr3;

}
```

A part of messages from gcc compiler are following,

```
/home/.../pointer.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Element findCorrespondingFirst(Element&, std::vector<_RealType>&) [with Element = Pointer<TestA, Function0>]’:
/home/.../pointer.hpp:120:56:   required from here
/home/.../pointer.hpp:68:11: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Pointer<TestA, Function0>’ and ‘Pointer<TestA, Function0>’)
   if (obj == o) {  // this dispatches an error massage
           ^
/home/.../pointer.hpp:68:11: note: candidates are:
/home/.../pointer.hpp:39:7: note: bool Pointer<T, Functions>::operator==(Pointer<T, Functions>&) [with T = TestA; Functions = Function0] <deleted>
    bool operator== (Pointer& cmp) = delete;  // ***** This line gives a warning
   ^
/home/.../pointer.hpp:23:14: note: bool operator==(Pointer<TestA, Function0>&, Pointer<TestA, Function0>&)
friend bool operator== (Derived& org, Derived& cmp) {  // ***** This line gives a warning
          ^
```

Thank you very much again.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the derived class to implement operator ==, if it has to. If the derived class does not need it, it should not declare the operator or resolve the ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you Dieter Lucking for answering. I wanted to discriminate data part(=derived class) and function part(=base class) although it has not strong reason; it is a kind of study of c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
bool operator== (Pointer& cmp) = delete;  // ***** This line gives a warning
```

is wrong in multiple ways. In fact, erasing it removes the problem (and you should just consider doing that, as it is unclear what purpose it serves, I must say).

Incidentally, the correct way to have defined it would be to declare it as

```
bool operator== (const Pointer<T, Functions>& cmp) const = delete;  // ***** This line gives a warning
```

Note that your class type is not `Pointer`, but rather `Pointer<T, Functions>`, and the correct `const`ness properties of this operator.

Your first `operator==` has const problems too.

---

I suggest you make the following changes:

```
friend bool operator== (const Derived& org, const Derived& cmp) {  // ***** This line gives a warning
    const Derived& org_value = static_cast<const Derived&>(org);
    const Derived& cmp_value = static_cast<const Derived&>(cmp);                                                                                                                                         
    return org_value == cmp_value;
}
```

Just erase the latter one:

```
// bool operator== (const Pointer<T, Functions>& cmp) const = delete;  // ***** This line gives a warning
```

Comment: Thank you Ami Tavory for for giving solution. My code might be a strange code but I tried to discriminate data part(=derived class) and function part(=base class); it is just for a study.

Comment: @mora It's very hard to understand such code in the comment. I don't even understand if this this a question to clarify the answer, or a separate question. I suggest you either open a separate question or modify this one, but not write questions in the comments.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad commenting. I will post the new question in another page. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome. Will be happy to look at the other question.